# How to save a file from mail using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Can I copy a file that was received via mail to a specific path in my application directory?

For example a "Browse" button which lets the user select a file.

Comment: You can't unless the user chooses to open the email attachment with your app.

Comment: Can user download the file to iPhone,  then  browse file that downloaded from some some directory?

Comment: As an iOS user you should know that the Mail app doesn't let you save an attachment to any sort of shared folder.